# Density of union of closed sets

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a separable, infinite dimensional Banach space. I want to find a countable collection $(V_n)$ of sets in $X$ that satisfy the following properties:

- For each $n$, $V_n$ is **closed** and **norm bounded**.
- $V_n\subseteq V_{n+1}$, for all $n$.
- $\cup V_n$ is a **proper**, **dense**,  subspace of $X$.

I am pretty convinced this is possible, but I failed to find such an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible. You start with a countable dense subset $\{ x_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ of $X$, which exists by the assumption of separability.

Then you construct a closed and bounded - let's say even compact - subset $V_n$ using $\{ x_0,\dotsc,x_n\}$, for each $n$. It could be a closed ball in some linear subspace, for example.

Do it right, and

$$\{x_n : n\in \mathbb{N}\} \subset \bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} V_n,$$

so the union on the right hand side is dense. It is a proper linear subspace, if done rightly, and proper by Baire's theorem.

Comment: I see, I think. If you take $V_n$ a multiple of the closed unit ball of $[x_1,x_2,\dots x_n]$ such that it contains all $x_k's$, for $1\leq k\leq n$, and also contains the previous $V_{n-1}$. Each $V_n$ has empty interior, so by Baire, their union cannot be $X$. Does this look right?

Comment: I suppose $[x_1,x_2,\dotsc,x_n]$ means the span of $\{x_1,x_2,\dotsc,x_n\}$. Then that is pretty much what I had in mind. You don't need $V_n$ to contain all the $x_k$ with $k \leqslant n$, you only need that the radii are nondecreasing, and converge to $+\infty$, taking the radius of $V_n$ to be $n$ is a simple choice. The union of the $V_n$ is then the span of $\{x_n :n\in\mathbb{N}\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $D=\{d_n\}$ be a countable dense subset of $X$. Let $V_1=\{d_1\}$ and define $V_i=V_{i-1}\cup \{d_i\}$.

Comment: I'm pretty sure "subspace" means "linear subspace".